# Salary to Employee puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction

A Managers paid a different amount to six Employees – A, B, C, D, P and R, not necessarily in the same order. The amount paid by him to each person is not necessarily a whole number. He paid them one after the other and paid no two persons at the same time.

> Further, it is known that
>   1.    P received 1200 which was the least amount paid by the Managers.
>   2.    Except the first and second payments, the amount paid by the Managers was the arithmetic mean of the previous two amounts paid by
>   him.
>   3.    He paid at least two of the Employees an amount more than 2200.
>   4.    R received his payment before B and D. Also, D received 150 more than R.
>   5.    P and C, who did not receive the highest payment, received their payments consecutively.

Source : Me

Please tell the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution (in order)

> $$A=3600, P=1200, C=2400, R=1800, B=2100, D=1950$$

Reasoning

> Given constraint number 2, it must be the case that the highest and lowest paid employees are the first two. Since $P$ is the lowest paid employee, he must be in the first two. $C$ is not the highest paid but is consecutive with $P$ so must be the third person paid. $R$ is also not the highest paid but is paid before $B$ and $D$ so $R$ must be fourth. This leaves $A$ as being paid first i.e, the order is $$A, P, C, R, B/D, D/B$$ Now, by rule 2, we have $R = \frac{P+C}{2} = 600 + \frac{C}{2}$. 
>  If $D$ is paid 5th, then we have $D = \frac{C+R}{2} = \frac{3R}{2} - 600$ which makes $R = 1500$ by rule 4. From here we could expand the whole solution set using rule 2 but only one employee, $A$, will have more than $2200$, contravening rule 3. So we must have that $B$ is 5th and $D$ is 6th. 
>  This means that $B = \frac{3R}{2} - 600$ and subsequently, $D = \frac{B+R}{2} = \frac{5R}{4} - 300$ and from rule 4, we get $R=1800$. 
>  Expanding this out using rule 2, we get $$A=3600, P=1200, C=2400, R=1800, B=2100, D=1950$$